# Django search_fields & Many-To-One Relations

Tags: python, django

As an example, I have two models: `Household` and `Person`:

```
from django.db import models
class Household(models.Model):
    address = # ...
class Person(models.Model):
    household = models.ForeignKey(Household)
    name = # ...
```

How can I search for `Household`s by names of `Person`s inside the Django admin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in [the docs for `search_fields`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields):

> You can also perform a related lookup on a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField with the lookup API "follow" notation:
>
> ```
> search_fields = ['foreign_key__related_fieldname']
> ```
>
> For example, if you have a blog entry with an author, the following definition would enable search blog entries by the email address of the author:
>
> ```
> search_fields = ['user__email']
> ```

This should also work "backwards", as in your example.

```
search_fields = ['person__name']
```